# User Default not giving value

Tags: ios, swift, userdefaults

I am setting some value in user defaults from my app. Then I added `NotificationContentExtention` it created another folder in project as sibling of main app folder. I tried to access same user default but it is not giving me that value there.

```
var sharedPreference    : UserDefaults  = UserDefaults.init(suiteName: "user-key-value")!
```

I am creating user default like this in both the places.

Comment: did you enable data sharing for both your app and extension?

Comment: When you call `init` you always create a new object, so the userDefaults cannot be the same. How are you saving your data into userDefaults?

Comment: No I did not do any such thing. @TarasChernyshenko

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can insert data using App group and access the same data using App groups with userdefaults,

For inserting data

```
var userDefaults = UserDefaults(suiteName: "<Your_App_Group>")
userDefaults?.set(your-object, forKey: your-key)
userDefaults?.synchronize()
```

And access the data in the same way.

Comment: can the suite name only be the app group name?